# javascript remove last-child in dynamically generating tr td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel

I have a function written in javascript that displays records of data once users upload excel file.

Here is my **HTML**

```
<table id="result" class="table table-striped table-responsive"></table>
```

and my **Javascript** for displaying uploaded data from excel

```
// draw HTML table based on sheet data
    var sheet = parseCSV.getSheet();
    var table = document.getElementById('result');
    var btnSave = document.getElementById('btnSave');
    table.innerHTML = "";
    var wrapper0 = $("#column0");
    var divMapping = document.getElementById('mapping');
    var rowArray = [];
    var columnArray = [];

    $('#table').show();

    sheet.forEach(function (el, i) {

        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        var button = document.createElement('td');
        el.forEach(function (el, i) {
            var cell = document.createElement('td');
            cell.innerHTML = el.value;

            row.appendChild(cell);

        });

        button.innerHTML = "<button class='btn btn-default'>View</button>";

        row.appendChild(button);

        table.appendChild(row);

    });
```

and here is a screenshot of the output I am getting.

[image]

I don't know why it generates extra `<tr>` on the bottom and on the `headers`.

Comment: well if you just want to remove the last tr you can use `$('#table tr:last').remove()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For removing button from header you can simply escape the button adding part in the loop.

```
    sheet.forEach(function (el, i) {

                var row = document.createElement('tr');
                var button = document.createElement('td');
                el.forEach(function (el, i) {
                    var cell = document.createElement('td');
                    cell.innerHTML = el.value;

                    row.appendChild(cell);

                });
              if(i != 0){
               button.innerHTML = "<button class='btn btn-
                                default'>View</button>";

               row.appendChild(button);
              }

            table.appendChild(row);

        });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. unfortunately, I only need the button to not generate on the first row.

Comment: @Terence I have added a check inside the loop for not adding button for first index.

Answer (score 0):

`sheet` may be returning one extra `row` with iteration,

Just add this check before adding the `view` button

```
if ( row.children && row.children )
{
   row.appendChild(button); 
}
```

This will ensure that button is added only if other cells have been pushed to the `row` already.

> and on the headers.

Add another check to avoid adding to headers

```
if ( row.children && row.children && i ) //check if i != 0
{
   row.appendChild(button); 
}
```